# xcode redirecting to a viewcontroller with uinavigation from login

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

Finally made my api login to work but I just bumped into a huge road block with redirecting to the main page after login. My storyboard looks like this

[image: current storyboard]

So I have all my processes on that submit button and after the validations pass I want to redirect to the Events page but it would always cache and would give me this exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue
>   'LoginSuccess'. Push segues can only be used when the source
>   controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'

This is the line that pushes to the next page

```
if(user.isValid){
        // go to next page
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSuccess" sender:self];
    }
    else{
            // else refresh current page
    }
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your login view controller should be embedded in a `UINavigationController` if you want to use a push segue on it.

You should have something like this:

```
-(initial view controller)-> [UINavigationController] -(embed)- LoginViewController -(push)-> EventsListViewController
```

**EDIT:** *(from comments)* If you really want to use a push segue, you need to put it in a navigation controller; else, you may have to change the screens via code (by changing `appDelegate.window.rootViewController`), or via a modal segue. However, if you use a modal segue, you cannot show any other controllers using a modal segue. (You cannot show a controller modally if the current view controller has already been shown modally.)

So far, I have only used the changing the rootViewController via code. If you embed the LoginViewController in the UINavigationController, you might have to handle the Back button as logout (when in EventsListViewController), or when popping view controllers in the navigation controller.

Comment: is the (initial view controller) like a splash page? that goes straight to the UINavigationalController? Is there any other way I can go to that page without embedding the login in the NavigationalController (without the push segue?)?

Comment: The initial view controller is the first screen you see when you open the app. In your storyboard, that is your login screen. I just meant that if you really want to use a push segue, you need to put it in a navigation controller; else, you may have to change the screens via code, or via a modal segue.

Comment: So if I opt to change the screens via code the login controller doesn't need to have a conection on the storyboard? Also, didn't really know what i was doing so I guess Imma change the seque to modal and see how it works.

Comment: Aside from being the initial view controller, yes, the login controller will have no connection in the storyboard. (My thinking here is you will change `appDelegate.window.rootViewController`.) Just came to mind: if you use the modal segue, you cannot show any other controllers using a modal segue. (You cannot show a controller modally if the current view controller has already been shown modally.)

Comment: I see what your saying. So is it easier to just have the UINavigationController embedded on the LoginView and just use that all the way?

Comment: So far, I have only used the changing the `rootViewController` via code. If you embed the LoginViewController in the UINavigationController, you might have to handle the Back button as logout (when in EventsListViewController), or when popping view controllers in the navigation controller.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Was wondering how do I make the back button a logout? I'm thinking I should remove the NSUserDefaults that I stored after login. Can you put code on that button when clicked?

Comment: In your `EventsListViewController`, you can set `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` to a `UIBarButtonItem` that you make and on which you specify the target.